# ARDUINO expected ';' before 'delay'

Tags: c++, pwm

I want to shine LED in 64 of 255 duty cycles = level of brightness but it pops up this error (see picture). Can anybody tell me why and help me ? Thank you.

```
void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:

}

void loop() {
  
  analogWrite(11, 64)
  delay{1000};
  analogWrite(11, 0)
  delay(1000);
  
  
  
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:

}
```

[image]

Comment: The error message (and the title of your post) tells you everything you need to fix your code, really.

Answer (score 1):

You should write ";" end of each lines.

```
analogWrite(11, 64);
delay(1000);
analogWrite(11, 0);
delay(1000);
```

Comment: This advice helped a lot :) Great, it works already. 

Thank you very much Furkan

Comment: Did you check connects? You should check that long leg of led is connected with arduino.

Comment: It works already, thank you very much. I had also broken LED and with new one it works perfectly :)

Comment: Good job. See you...